# Missing classes from the assembly file created by sbt assembly

Tags: jar, sbt

I have a project that uses sbt 0.13.6 with the assembly 0.12.0 plugin to create the farJar. My `build.sbt` is:

```
name := "test"

version := "0.0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.10.4"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  ("org.apache.kafka" % "kafka_2.10" % "0.8.0" % "provided").
    exclude("javax.jms", "jms").
    exclude("com.sun.jdmk", "jmxtools").
    exclude("com.sun.jmx", "jmxri").
    exclude("org.slf4j", "slf4j-simple")
)
```

When I run `sbt assembly` I get a file called `target/scala-2.10/test-assembly-0.0.1.jar` but it is missing some kafka classes, included the one that I need at runtime:

```
> diff <(jar -tf /home/rief/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.kafka/kafka_2.10/jars/kafka_2.10-0.8.0.jar) <(jar -tf target/scala-2.10/test-assembly-0.0.1.jar) | grep "^<"
...
kafka/consumer/ZookeeperConsumerConnector$ZKRebalancerListener$$anonfun$kafka$consumer$ZookeeperConsumerConnector$ZKRebalancerListener$$closeFetchersForQueues$1.class
...
```

Is this a correct behaviour? How can I include `kafka` in my fatJar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the intended behavior. `% "provided"` is skipped, since it's intention is to provide those classes from the container like Apache Spark, Kafka etc.
If you want everything in it here's what you can do:

```scala
fullClasspath in assembly := (fullClasspath in Compile).value
```

Comment: Also without "provided" I got the same problem.